# jQuery ajax POST type form submits multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've seen many solutions over this question. But any of this doesn't solve my problem.
When i use:

```
$("form#sending-notice-form").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ..
});
```

Then, form submit once but my form validation library doesn't work.
When i use:

```
$("form#sending-notice-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ..
});
```

OR

```
$("form#sending-notice-form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ..
});
```

Then, Validation library work fine but form submit multiple times.
When i use:

```
$("form#sending-notice-form").submit(function (e) {
    $(this).unbind("submit");
    e.preventDefault();
    ..
});
```

Then, Validation library work for first submit. when submit twice or double click the submit button then open form ACTION url in the browser.

Comment: *"but my form validation library library doesn't work"* - "doesn't work" means nothing. What does not work? Also, if your question is about form validation, maybe you should include the code you use for form validation.

Comment: If its submitting multiple times, why dont you try on click of button and then inside that, write validation and submission code.

Comment: every thing is ok. but validation library does not work. for when require field empty then does not showing any message under the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.on()` :

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#sending-notice-form', function() {
    /*
         your validation code here
    */

    //then 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry, form submits multiple time.

Comment: do you have example link, like jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

**Try it once..**

```
jQuery("form#sending-notice-form").submit(function (e) {
            if (jQuery("#conatct_form_id").valid()) {
               // Code
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I hope it's helpful to yo.....